# Using jQuery .each() to read any html value and change it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I want to use the jQuery function .each() to apply a possible change to a value.

I have a bunch of labels in  tags with a class="temp". If I have a switch to switch between Celsius and Fahrenheit I would like to update all html elements with the temp class. I will retrieve the value from the span, then update the span to have the new temperature.

Span tags look like

```
<span class=​"temp" id=​"holder_1443531366" style=​"text-align:​center;​ display:​inline-block;​">​<span style>​86.1​</span>
​<span style=​"padding-left:​3px;​">​°F​</span>​
</span>​
```

Im sure this isnt the best looking html element, i didnt make it, im using a website to build a web dashboard and cannot actually change these directly.

There is other parts to this code, but I just need the main part working.

```
//Find all elements with span class="temp"
var temps = [];
var html;
var pHtml;
temps = jQuery('.temp').toArray();
html = jQuery('.temp').html();
//pHtml = jQuery('.temp').parseHTML();
if(temps != null){
    console.log("Temps -> "+temps.length);
    console.log("html -> "+html);

    for(var i = 0; i < temps.length; i++){          
        console.log(temps[i]);      
    }

}else {
    console.log("No temps found");
}
```

I have currently two elements to find and this is the output so far

```
Attempting to find temp classes
Temps -> 2
html -> <span style="">86.0</span><span style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span>
<span class=​"temp" id=​"holder_1443531366" style=​"text-align:​center;​ display:​inline-block;​">​<span style>​86.1​</span>​<span style=​"padding-left:​3px;​">​°F​</span>​</span>​
<span class=​"temp" id=​"holder_1443531376" style=​"text-align:​center;​ display:​inline-block;​">​<span style>​85.38​</span>​<span style=​"padding-left:​3px;​">​°F​</span>​</span>​
```

I save each element with the ".temp" class, find the temp (86.1) and then use that value to execute my temp converter function (or just some math right there).
With the new value, I will update the element from 86.1 -> the Celsius temp i just calculated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Im pretty much trying to save each element with the ".temp" class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to toggle back and forth

```js
$('a').click(function () {
    $('span.temp').each(function () {

        if ($(this).find('span:last').text() == '°F') {
            $(this).find('span:last').text('°C');
            $(this).find('span:first').text(parseFloat((($(this).find('span:first').text() - 32) * 5) / 9).toFixed(2))
        } else {
            $(this).find('span:last').text('°F');
            $(this).find('span:first').text(parseFloat((($(this).find('span:first').text() * 9) / 5) + 32).toFixed(2))
        }
    })
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'switch to Fahrenheit' ? 'switch to Celsius' : 'switch to Fahrenheit')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;">
    <span style>86.1</span>
 <span style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span>
</span>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531367" style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;">
    <span style>212</span>
 <span style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span>
</span>
<a href="#">switch to Celsius</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

what this code does, is that on click of the link, it cycles through each element with class `.temp` and gets the `.degrees`, converts that to Celsius, and then changes the F to a C.

i added classes on both spans to accomplish this (`.degrees` and `.degType`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.toC').on('click', function() {
     $('.temp').each(function() {
            var degrees = $(this).find('.degrees').html();
            var cTemp = (parseFloat(degrees - 32) * (parseFloat(5/9))).toFixed(1);
            $(this).find('.degrees').html(cTemp);
            $(this).find('.degType').html('°C');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;"><span class="degrees">86.1</span>
<span class="degType" style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span>
</span>
<br/><br/>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;"><span class="degrees">212</span>
<span class="degType" style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span>
</span>
<br/><br/>
<a class="toC" href="#">to Celcius<a/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.find()` to filter first `span` , `.html(function(index, html){})` to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius , select next `span` to change `F` to `C`

```js
$(".temp").each(function(index, el) {
  $(this).find("span:first").html(function(_, temp) {
    return ((temp - 32) * 5/9).toFixed(2)
  }).next("span").html(function(_, sym) {
    return sym.slice(0,1) + "C"
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style= "text-align:​center;display:inline-block;"><span style>86.1</span><span style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span></span>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531376" style= "text-align:center;display:inline-block;"><span style>85.38</span><span style="padding-left:3px;">°F</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a working example and tested it to be working

http://jsfiddle.net/a2dax16t/

I've created a sample set of spans as you did, but added a button to trigger the function:

```
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;">86.1</span>

<br/>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;">99</span>

<br/>
<span class="temp" id="holder_1443531366" style="text-align:center;display:inline-block;">102</span>
</span>
<br/>
<button id="btnCelsius">Convert</button>
```

and here is my function:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#btnCelsius").click(function () {
        $(".temp").each(function () {
            var newValue = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(toCelsius(newValue));
        });
    });
});

function toCelsius(f) {
    return (5 / 9) * (f - 32);
}
```

as you can see, I've created a function to convert to celsius, and used it inside the `each()` function, and tested it and it's working.

please give it a try and let me know if this is what you want or that you need any extra modifications.